# Why does Bash trap not capture the exit status for an undefined variable?

Tags: bash

I need to capture error conditions in a Bash script using a trap. For this reason I've  both `set -e` AND `set -u` in my script. However I've noticed that the trap defined in the script is not getting the error status. For example:

```
set -e
set -u

on_exit() {
  exit_status=$?
  echo exit_status=$exit_status
  exit $exit_status
}

trap on_exit EXIT

X=$Y
```

The above snippet prints:

```
line 12: Y: unbound variable
exit_status=0
```

Whereas I was expecting the error status to be non-zero. After removing `set -e` the error status is correctly reported as 1.

What's the reason for that?

Bash version: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

Comment: returns `exit_status=1

jdoodle.sh: line 13: Y: unbound variable` on [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online)

Comment: Maybe `ret` is defined in your program and is equal to 0? If so, `${ret:=$?}` will be `$ret`. Can you print `ret` before in the `on_exit` function?

Comment: `ret` is not significative in this example, I've removed it, same behaviour it returns 0 while I was expecting 1.

Comment: @pditommaso: Can you remove the assignment of the exit code to `exit_status` variable and call directly as `echo exit_status=$?`

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? I can reproduce your issue in 3.2, but it has the expected exit status in 4.4.

Comment: Looks like a bug that was fixed in `bash` 4.1.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm using version 3.2.57 more recent version are working fine. We can conclude that's a bug.

Comment: Hmm. Thought we already had an entry for this interaction in the knowledge base, but I'm having some trouble finding it. (As an aside, I [strongly advise against using `set -e`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- skip the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry, or see [this chart](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) describing how inconsistent and variable its behavior is across shells).

Comment: @chepner: Could you point to the release notes, that says about this fix in 4.1

Comment: @Inian I'll take a look; I was just running the same command one version at a time, and noticed it got fixed between 4.0 and 4.1

Comment: Huh; I did not expect to find something so specific :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the change log between 4.0 and 4.1:

> x.  Fixed a bug that caused $? to not be set correctly when referencing an
>       unset variable with set -u and set -e enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Bash does trigger ERR trap [Correct behavior of EXIT and ERR traps when using `set -eu`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208112/correct-behavior-of-exit-and-err-traps-when-using-set-eu)
, but we can handle it partially this way:

##### defining a handler function

```
function _unbound_variable_handler(){
    case $1 in
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST | MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD | MC_ACCESS_KEY | MC_ACCESS_KEY )
            echo please set $1 in your .env file or export it
        ;;
        * )
            echo please set $1 first then run the script.
        ;;
    esac

    exit $?;
}
```

##### set the handler for any variable you want to take care of

```
echo WORDPRESS_DB_HOST ${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:?"$(_unbound_variable_handler WORDPRESS_DB_HOST)"}
```

##### sample

```
# bash strict mode
set -Eeuo pipefail
# debug mode
# set -x

function _unbound_variable_handler(){
    case $1 in
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST | MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD | MC_ACCESS_KEY | MC_ACCESS_KEY )
            echo please set $1 in your .env file or export it
        ;;
        * )
            echo please set $1 first then run the script.
        ;;
    esac

    exit $?;
}

echo WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:?"$(_unbound_variable_handler WORDPRESS_DB_HOST)"}
```

##### output

> ub.sh: line 20: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: please set WORDPRESS_DB_HOST in
> your .env file or export it

---

NOTE

This syntax is for exiting immediately with the **message** you set
`${varname:?"message"}` and I used a function instead of a **message**

##### sample

```
echo WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST:-"Error on line $LINENO - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST has not been set"}
```

##### output

> WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: Error on line 22 - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST has not been set

and this syntax is for setting a value to the varname
`${varname:-"message"}`

---

```sh
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```